# Logic error with Python while loops using 'and' and 'or' conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I am having trouble figuring out a piece of code that looks like it should be working but it isn't working how I'd like it too.

I have made an example loop to demonstrate the issue I am having:

```
a = input("Answer: ")

while a != '1' or '2':
    print("That's incorrect try again")
    a = input("Answer: ")
```

The intent would be that I have the user input the condition till it was right but when I put in the correct answer this is what happens.

```
Answer: 3
That's incorrect try again
Answer: 1
That's incorrect try again
Answer: 2
That's incorrect try again
```

This is the python shell output and as you can see when I put the wrong number in I get the right message as it is wrong but when I put the 2 correct answers in neither make it jump out of the loop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is always `True`

```
a != '1' or '2':
```

because it works like:

```
(a != '1') or '2'
```

and `'2'` is `True`